# Character Encoding pdf

Tags: pdftex, copy-paste

I compile my latex with pdflatex in texniccenter. The produced pdf looks good. But when I select a word and copy it over to a texteditor, some of the characters are wrong. for instance all german ö,ü,ä but also a word like anriffsvektor becomes angri_svektor, so both "f" become a "_". Are there any settings, I can setup with pdflatex for that?

Here is a mwe:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=11pt,oneside,parskip=half,headings=normal]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      


\begin{document}
angriffsvektor
\end{document}
```

And here is an [example pdf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1y2P_OuBVoO_yqe9pTiDPIsLtnJmfWAPu) file

Comment: Build an minimal working example (»MWE«) and add it to your question. We can easily have educated guesses what the cause of the vanishing ligatures may be (use package cmap, e.g.), but for sure you only know after testing.

Comment: Copies correctly for me (using TL2018 and TeXworks). Which viewer did you try?

Comment: I use AdobeAcrobat Reader DC, but I don't think it's an viewer issue, I think it's more a compile issue.

Comment: Using your example pdf I can tell that you did not use a T1 enabled font (or did not use the `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` line) to produce it. Try using `lmodern` for example (which looks very much like Computer Modern but is a T1 font). But my viewer (the fabulous MuPDF) did copy the ff ligature correctly as two fs. Only the umlaut ü was copied as `¨u`.

Comment: The MWE you posted above doesn't make any problem, both the ff ligature and the umlaut are copied correctly by MuPDF. If that's not the case for your setup, this is ought to be a viewer problem.

Comment: \usepackage{lmodern} did the trick! thanks a lot. I thought the default font should be a T1 Font...!?